# Why does c-electric-semi&comma indent incorrectly when using eglot?

Tags: c#, emacs

I'm switching to `eglot` from `lsp-mode`, and I'm getting an unexpected indentation in C# code.  I have a minimal editorconfig file that just sets `indent_size` to `2`.  Things seem fine until I hit a semicolon, at which point the current line and the next line both get indented further than they should.  Here's a before:

```
public static class Stuff
{
  public static T DoAThing<T>(T obj)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(obj)
  }
}
```

And here's what happens when I hit `;`:

```
public static class Stuff
{
  public static T DoAThing<T>(T obj)
  {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

Looking at the help for `;`, I see that it's bound to `c-electric-semi&comma`, but it seems like setting `c-syntactic-indentation` to `nil` doesn't actually prevent the indentation, which is counter to what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem in the future, `c-electric-semi&comma` was a red herring.  The problem was that `omnisharp-roslyn` wasn't configured to respect `editorconfig` settings.  The way to do that is to go to `~/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json` and make sure that you've got this enabled:

```
{
  "FormattingOptions": {
    "enableEditorConfigSupport": true
  }
}
```